# How to disable future date and today date for date of birth in android kotlin

Tags: android, datepicker

```
 calendar.setOnClickListener {
            datePicker =  DatePickerDialog(this, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int ->
                val curDate = String.format("%d-%02d-%02d", year , (month+1), dayOfMonth)
                date_text.setText(curDate)
            }, year, month, day)
         
            datePicker!!.datePicker.maxDate = (System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000)
            datePicker!!.show()
        }
```

How to select the dob must be a date before today. Please help me to do this

Answer (score 0):

Use it this way :

```
val calender = getInstance()
calender[HOUR_OF_DAY] = 0
calender[MINUTE] = 0
calender[SECOND] = 0
```

Then use this in your code

```
datePicker!!.datePicker.maxDate = calendar.timeInMillis
```

This way the max date will be set to midnight of today's date.